# Is it necessary to call youtube api to load a list if videos?

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube-api

I want to embed a list of youtube videos on my web-page. I saw the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) but is it necessary to load the www.youtube.com/iframe_api" and to call onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(). Is there a simple way to declare iframes directly on my page (from there ids) instead of 'manually' call the api. If yes, what are the advantages of doing so ? (knowing I only need to stop and play the vide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly load a list of video with an iframe tag. You can use this site to build the proper code easily : [youtube player demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo)

If you do not need the others API calls, it's an easy way to do it. The only issue would be if they changes the way youtube iframe elements are encoded, obviously, using their API to "abstract" the iframe layer is a way to prevent those kind of issues.

Comment: Thank you, I ma going to try it !

Answer (score 1):

You can load a playlist using the mechanism described here: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/07/say-hello-to-new-playlist-player.html, also, specifying a list of comma-separated video IDs also works, see the playlist player parameter defined here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist